# How to mock the forEach elements which is iterate over the minioclient collection?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, junit, minio

I am using `minioClient.listObjects` to fetch all the objects from `s3`. It returns the `iterable Result<Item>`. Here I was iterating over these results.

```
public class S3class
{       //this class is part of spring boot application. So here no main class.
     public void s3method(){
        MinioClient minioClient = MinioClient.builder().endpoint("")
        .build();

        Iterable<Result<Item>> results = minioClient.listObjects(
                ListObjectsArgs.builder()
                        .bucket("bucket_name")
                        .recursive(true)
                        .startAfter("something")
                        .build()
        );

        for (Result<Item> result : results) {
            Item item;
            try {
                System.out.println("inside try");
                item = result.get();     ///it returns null. How to mock this
                System.out.println("if it reach here, no problem");
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("problem is here");
                throw new Error();
            }

            Tags tags = minioClient.getObjectTags(
                    GetObjectTagsArgs.builder()
                            .bucket(bucket)
                            .object(item.objectName()) //beforei was tried like result.get().objectName(). but it fails. Here always i want to return "dummy" string. but it gives **null**.
                            .build()
            );
         }
     }
}
```

**Testing method**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testclass{
@InjectMocks
    private S3class s3class;
@Mock
    private MinioClient minioClient;
@Mock
    private Result<Item> result;

    @Mock
    private Iterable<Result<Item>> results;

    @Mock
    private Iterator<Result<Item>> iterator;

    @Mock
    private Consumer<Result<Item>> consumer;
      
    public void testmethod(){
        Item item = new Item("dummy") {};
        result = new Result<Item>(item);
        // Mockito.when(result.get()).thenReturn(item);
      
        Mockito.when(minioClient.listObjects(
                    Mockito.any(ListObjectsArgs.class)))
                    .thenReturn(results);
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(results).forEach(consumer);
        Mockito.when(iterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true,false);
        Mockito.when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(result);
        Mockito.when(results.iterator()).thenReturn(iterator);
 
         s3class.s3method();
      }
}
```

I mocked the `minioclient`. But I can't mock this `result.get().objectName()`. I used `when and thenReturn` but no use. Here I want to return `some string` whenever `result.get().objectName()` called.

I tried this whole day in many ways. But I couldn't. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you do not have to mock `iterator` `results` `result`

Comment: That's okay. Then, how do I get my desired output? Please share the correct way of mocking this code.

Comment: Please provide more info of your class and test class